# Is there any limit on how much text asp:label control can hold?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should I use it if I wanna store really long text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `<asp:literal enableviewstate='false' ...` as it is apparently more lightweight than a `<asp:label ...`

> A Literal control is much more light
>   weight than a Label.. it's meant to
>   write out text/html directly to the
>   browser.  A Label is little bulkier
>   than a Literal, but has all benefits
>   of a WebControl such as styling
>   options etc.

It should also be noted that a label will wrap your content with `<span> ... </span>` whereas  a literal does not.

Comment: Unless you use the `AssociatedControlId` property, in which case ASP.NET will render a `<label>`.

Answer (score 1):

A label is the HTML equivalent of a span in when rendered. It holds any valid string.

Comment: Unless you use the `AssociatedControlId` property, in which case ASP.NET will render a `<label>`.